# 1024 connection limit on a single port

Tags: networking, centos, centos6

I'm running a shoutcast v1 streaming server on a CentOS box. When I start the server as root, I can stream to 1200-1300 clients without a problem.

However, when I run the server as a different user (ccuser) the shoutcast server freezes when the connections reach to ~1019 something.

I have already edited /etc/security/limits.conf with the appropriate setting for both root & ccuser, and after a reboot, ulimit -a confirms it:

```
root@nsxxxxxx ~/monitoring # su - ccuser
-bash-4.1$ ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 515170
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 16384
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 1024
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

I'm guessing that there is some other safeguard/setting that prohibits normal users to have more than ~1000 connections on a single port. Anyone has any ideas?

Comment: Check your pam.d It is most likely overrides the settings with this rule /etc/security/limits.d/90-nproc.conf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each connection is an open socket, each socket is a file, -> therefore that user has file limits restricted to 1024 open files.

Actually i think your pam is enforcing to use /etc/security/limits.d/90-nproc.conf which overrides your set soft limit put up in limits.conf.

Comment: Yeah, pam was ovveriding the nproc limit for everyone except root (setting it back to 1024). I've changed that, Have to wait till the next maintenance timeframe for a reboot and see if it works. Cheers